# c# Azure Event Grid - VM Activity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

I'm very new to the Azure Event Grid and have a question on how to do something.  I'd like to be able to register to receive events about VM activities (start/deallocate, etc) in a c#/.Net application in order to be able to react to certain VM events.

Has anyone done something like this?  All the c# Azure Event Grid examples I can find seem to deal with getting notifications about items being removed from/added to blob storage in Azure.

Comment: According to [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) official document, it seems that VM service is not supported by Azure Event Grid now. urrently, the following Azure services have built-in publisher support for event grid:+

Azure Subscriptions (management operations),
Custom Topics,
Event Hubs,
Resource Groups (management operations),
Storage Blob

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial, it explains how to monitor VM changes:

- [Tutorial: Monitor virtual machine changes with Azure Event Grid and Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app)

In a nutshell:

- Create a logic app with an eventgrid trigger.
- Specify the resource group and resource (VM) name.
- Filter the events you're interested in based on the operationname:
  `@equals(triggerBody()?['data']['operationName'], 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write')`

Comment: Is there any way where we can monitor internal services which are installed/deployed in the virtual machine ? for ex. : if any service is stopped (which was running for sometime) , would like to send this as event to event grid . is this possible ?

Comment: I imagine it is possible wih a little bit of code :-)

Comment: Ohh , yeah. any reference to sample code would be much helpful :)